# How to solve for sorted anagrams

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, collections

I have a list of words as follows.

`pear
amleth
dormitory
tinsel
dirty room
hamlet
listen
silnet`

I want to find out all anagrams and list them in sorted order. If nothing is found just output that word. So in the above case the output should be.

`amleth,hamlet
dirty room,dormitory
listen,silnet,tinsel
pear`

Below is the java code I have written for that.

```
public class Anagram {

    private  boolean isAnagram(String s1, String s2) {

        if (s1.length() != s2.length()) {
            return false;
        }
        Map<Character, Integer> anagramMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ++ch) 
             anagramMap.put(ch, 0); 
        for(int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++){
            anagramMap.put(s1.charAt(i), anagramMap.get(s1.charAt(i))+1);
        }
        for(int j=0; j<s2.length(); j++) {
            if (anagramMap.get(s2.charAt(j)) != 0) {
                anagramMap.put(s2.charAt(j), anagramMap.get(s2.charAt(j)) - 1);
            }
        }
        for(int value : anagramMap.values()) {
            if (value != 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    private void solveChallenge(List<String> words) {
        for(int i=0 ;i<(words.size()-1); i++) {
            Set<String> result = new TreeSet<>();
            for(int j=(i+1); j< words.size(); j++) {
                if (isAnagram(words.get(i), words.get(j))){
                    result.add(words.get(i) + " " + words.get(j));
                    System.out.println(result);
                    words.remove(j);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Anagram anagram = new Anagram();
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            Integer numTestCases = Integer.parseInt(line);
            while (--numTestCases >= 0){
                words.add(reader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+","").toLowerCase());
            }
            System.out.println(words);
            new Anagram().solveChallenge(words);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

But it's not listing the desired output. The output I get is
`[amleth hamlet]
[dormitory dirtyroom]
[tinsel lisetn]`

Can someone tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: "But it's not listing the exact output. " <- What do you mean by that? How can an output not be the exact output (itself)?

Comment: _But it's not listing the desired output._ can you show the output you're getting?

Comment: I don't see how you could expect your program to produce the output you describe.  It compares and outputs results pairwise, but you want to accommodate groups of more than two anagrams.  Additionally, you strip spaces from the words on input; those are lost -- you cannot reproduce them when you output the result.  Furthermore, you have no mechanism at all for outputting inputs that are not anagrams of any other input.  **You need a completely different approach**.

Comment: Consider forming groups of mutual anagrams as you read the input, and delaying output until after you've read and grouped the whole input.

Comment: While I am convinced that your `isAnagram` method works correctly, the standard way of checking anagrams is sorting the letters and comparing the sorted order. Since amleth and hamlet both yield aehlmt, they are anagrams. The other advantage is that you can use a `Map<String, List<String>> to hold your anagrams, so all of listen, silnet and tinsel would be stored under the key eilnst.

Comment: `boolean isAnagram(String a, String b) { char[] ca = a.toCharArray(); char[] cb = b.toCharArray(); Arrays.sort(ca); Arrays.sort(cb); return Arrays.equals(ca,cb);}`

Comment: @slim, thanks for illustrating my point. Your code won’t accept `dormitory` and `dirty room` as anagrams because of the space, but the necessary modification should not be difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made few mistakes in the code. First of all you need to change the logic of storing the anagrams in the set. You are storing here `pair` in the set rather you should store all anagrams here. So you can have a `StringBuilder` to store the `anagrams` in a `single` pass and after the iteration, You can add it to the set.

Another mistake is in this loop:

```
for(int j=(i+1); j< words.size(); j++) {
    if (isAnagram(words.get(i), words.get(j))){
        result.add(words.get(i) + " " + words.get(j));
        System.out.println(result);
        words.remove(j);
    }
}
```

Here you are removing an `element` from the list and then incrementing `j` So it is possible that after removal, all elements gets shifted ahead by `1` place so If next element is `anagram` then you will miss it as you are incrementing `j`. And last mistake is that you need to check for all elements of `words` list. Because it may possible that last element is not anagram with any other element, Then it is required to be taken separately.

So Make few changes in `solveChallenge()` function:

```
private void solveChallenge(List<String> words) {
    for(int i=0 ;i<(words.size()); i++) {
        Set<String> result = new TreeSet<>();
        StringBuilder resultant_string = new StringBuilder(words.get(i)); //To store the all anagrams
        for(int j=(i+1); j< words.size(); j++) {
            if (isAnagram(words.get(i), words.get(j))){
                resultant_string.append(" ").append(words.get(j));
                words.remove(j);
                j--;       //If anagram found, stay on the current element
            }
        }
        result.add(resultant_string.toString());
        System.out.println(resultant_string);
    }
}
```

As per your need, I have made some changes in the program.

Code:

```
class Anagram {

    private  boolean isAnagram(String s1, String s2) {
        s1=s1.replaceAll("\\s+","");
        s2=s2.replaceAll("\\s+","");
        if (s1.length() != s2.length()) {
            return false;
        }
        Map<Character, Integer> anagramMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ++ch) 
             anagramMap.put(ch, 0); 
        for(int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++){
            anagramMap.put(s1.charAt(i), anagramMap.get(s1.charAt(i))+1);
        }
        for(int j=0; j<s2.length(); j++) {
            if (anagramMap.get(s2.charAt(j)) != 0) {
                anagramMap.put(s2.charAt(j), anagramMap.get(s2.charAt(j)) - 1);
            }
        }
        for(int value : anagramMap.values()) {
            if (value != 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    private void solveChallenge(List<String> words) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0 ;i<(words.size()); i++) {
            List<String> resultant_strings=new ArrayList<> ();
            resultant_strings.add(words.get(i));

            for(int j=(i+1); j< words.size(); j++) {
                if (isAnagram(words.get(i), words.get(j))){
                    resultant_strings.add(words.get(j));
                    words.remove(j);
                    j--;
                }
            }
            Collections.sort(resultant_strings);
            String resultant_string=resultant_strings.toString();
            result.add(resultant_string);
        }
        Collections.sort(result);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Anagram anagram = new Anagram();
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            Integer numTestCases = Integer.parseInt(line);
            while (--numTestCases >= 0){
                words.add(reader.readLine().toLowerCase());
            }
            System.out.println(words);
            new Anagram().solveChallenge(words);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Prints result:

```
[[amleth, hamlet], [dirty room, dormitory], [listen, silnet, tinsel], [pear]]
```

Comment: This works fine for most parts but omits the space in "dirty room" in the output. also the entire output needs to be sorted i.e pear should come at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem

```
public class Anagram {

private  boolean isAnagram(String s1, String s2) {

    if (s1.length() != s2.length()) {
        return false;
    }
    Map<Character, Integer> anagramMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ++ch) 
         anagramMap.put(ch, 0); 
    for(int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++){
        anagramMap.put(s1.charAt(i), anagramMap.get(s1.charAt(i))+1);
    }
    for(int j=0; j<s2.length(); j++) {
        if (anagramMap.get(s2.charAt(j)) != 0) {
            anagramMap.put(s2.charAt(j), anagramMap.get(s2.charAt(j)) - 1);
        }
    }
    for(int value : anagramMap.values()) {
        if (value != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
private void solveChallenge(List<String> words) {
    for(int i=0 ;i<(words.size()-1); i++) {
        Set<String> result = new TreeSet<>();
        int j = i+1;
        while(j < words.size()) {
            if (isAnagram(words.get(i), words.get(j))){
                result.add(words.get(i) + " " + words.get(j));
                System.out.println(result);
                words.remove(j);
            } else {
             j++;
           }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Anagram anagram = new Anagram();
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        Integer numTestCases = Integer.parseInt(line);
        while (--numTestCases >= 0){
            words.add(reader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+","").toLowerCase());
        }
        System.out.println(words);
        new Anagram().solveChallenge(words);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

You should increment j only when you are not removing any element because that remove() method caused problems.

Now I would recommend you should use HashMap< String, ArrayList< String>> something like this data structure. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about it:

- for each word, create a `Map<Character, Integer>` that contains the characters of the word (excluding spaces) and the number of occurence - you have already done something similar
- then store them in a `Map<Map<Character, Integer>, List<String>>`, where the key is the map of occurences and the value is a list of all the words that match (anagrams). `Map::equals` will do the comparison automagically for you.

A sample implementation could look like this:

```
String[] words = ("pear", "amleth", ... }'
Map<Map<Integer, Long>, List<String>> characters = new HashMap<> ();
for (String word : words) {
  //here I'm using a stream, but you can build the occurences map manually
  Map<Integer, Long> occurences = word.replaceAll("\\s+", "") //remove spaces
                   .chars().boxed()
                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.counting()));

  if (characters.containsKey(occurences)) { //anagram found !
    characters.get(occurences).add(word); //add the word to the list
  } else { //no anagram found, create the list, with only one item
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<> ();
    list.add(word);
    characters.put(occurences, list);
  }
}

//you may want to sort the lists here

characters.values().forEach(System.out::println);
```